# Second use of input file doesn't trigger onchange anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have a picture upload button that automatically uploads the file when selected from the browse window.
Nonetheless, it doesn't work the second time around and that is because the onChange event is not triggered. Why is that so?

**Here is a use case:**
1. On click of the button, I call uploadMessagePicture(), which opens the browse window.
2. When the user has selected a picture, a onChange event is detected which triggers the ajaxFileUpload() and shows the photo editor area.
3. When the upload is complete, a preview of the image is shown.
4. The user deletes the picture by calling deleteMessageImage() (which also clears the fields and hides the photo editor).
5. The user tries to upload another picture.

At this point, the browse window appears, but when I select a picture, the onChange event is not triggered so nothing happens... (Also, it doesn't seem like the filename is even transfered to the input' value field.)
I'm on Firefox 23.0.1

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<a class="im-photo-btn" href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:uploadMessagePicture();"><i class="icon-join-photo"></i></a>

<div class="editor-photoarea" id="editor-photoarea" style="display:none;">
    <input name="image_message_file" type="hidden" id="image_message_file" value="" />
    <div id="image_message_upload">
        <input name="image-message" type="file" id="image-message" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;" /> 
        <!-- hide it and trigger it from the photo btn (need both display:none + visibility:hiden for browser compatibility) -->
    </div>
    <div class="loading" id="image_message_loading" style="display:none;"><img alt="<?php echo $lang["Loading"];?>" src="lib/immedia/img/ajax-loader.gif" /> <?php echo $lang["Loading"];?></div>
    <div class="preview" style="display:none;" id="image_message_preview">
        <!-- <div>Image preview :</div>
        <div id='small_message_msg'></div>
            <img src='' />
            <div class='btnoptions'>
                <a onclick='javascript:deleteMessageImage();' href='javascript:;' class='button' title="Delete photo">
                    <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick smsg'></span>Delete
                </a>
         </div>-->
</div>
```

**Here is the javascript to automatically upload the picture**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#image-message").on('change', function () {
        $('#editor-photoarea').show();
        ajaxFileUploadMessagePicture();
    });
});

function uploadMessagePicture(){
    //trigger the browse click
    if($('#image_message_file').val() == ''){
        //let the person upload a file only if none are there
        $('#image-message').trigger('click');
    }
}

function ajaxFileUploadMessagePicture(){
$("#msg_error_no_image_message").hide();

var imageName = $("#image-message").val();
if(imageName != ''){
    $("#image_message_loading").show();
    $('#sendBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $.ajaxFileUpload
    (
        {
            url:siteRegionDir+'lib/immedia/uploadMessagePicture.php',
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'image-message',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, status)
            {
                updateMessagePicture(data);             
            },
            error: function (data, status, e)
            {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    )   
}else{
    $("#msg_error_no_image_message").show();
}
return false;
}
```

**Here is the Javascript to delete the picture and clear the fields**

```
function deleteMessageImage(){
//delete the image
var file = $("#image_message_file").val();

if(file != '') {
    $.post(siteRegionDir+'lib/immedia/deleteMessagePicture.php',{filename:file}, function(data) {   
            clearPictureAttachment();               
            $('#editor-photoarea').hide();//make sure it is hidden
        },"html"  
    );
}else{      
    clearPictureAttachment();
    $('#editor-photoarea').hide();//make sure it is hidden
}
}

function clearPictureAttachment(){
//var control = $("#image-message");
$("#image-message").attr('value', '');
//control.replaceWith( control = control.clone( true ) );//so it resets it all, truw = keep the bound events
$("#image_message_file").attr('value', '');
$("#image_message_loading").hide();
$("#image_message_upload").show();
$("#image_message_preview").hide();
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess: Try resetting the form via JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to codingrhythm for leading me on the right track.
What I did was to actually just add the on("change") call again on the field.
So I only altered the clearPictureAttachment() function (called when deleting a picture) to this:

```
function clearPictureAttachment(){
$("#image-message").attr('value', '');    
$("#image_message_file").attr('value', '');
$("#image_message_loading").hide();
$("#image_message_upload").show();
$("#image_message_preview").hide();
//reenable the onchange to upload a picture
$("#image-message").on('change', function () {
    $('#editor-photoarea').show();
    ajaxFileUploadMessagePicture();
});
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Nice work. Helped me with a similar problem (event wouldn't fire because I was trying to open the same file). Although all I I needed to do was resetting the "value" property of the file input element (i.e., myInputElement.value='').

Comment: well done. Re-trigger the event after uploading a file works. Saved me from few hours to troubleshooting

Answer (score 106):

If you're using React or just javascript in general you can what you can also do is "reset" the value of the event target.

So If you have something like a component that can upload and "remove" an image:

```
<input type="file" onChange={onChange} />
```

your `onChange` can be:

```
onChange(event) {

    const files = event.target.files;

    // your logic here on what to do with files (maybe fetch the preview or something)

    // this line right below will reset the 
    // input field so if you removed it you can re-add the same file
    event.target.value = ''
}
```

Comment: For me it wouldn't compile unless it said `event.target.value = ''`

Comment: Updated the answer, sorry about that I was just typing this manually when I answered it and forgot to prepend the `event` variable

Answer (score 18):

My guess is that you test your functionality with the same picture file over and over again.

**If you select the same file, the onChange event of `input[type=file]` will not fire.**

Different file with the same name would not fire the event as well. Select a different image file - it will happen.

To avoid this you can reset the form to ensure that choosing a file will be performed on a clean `file` control

Comment: Same name or same file? What about the same filename in different folders? Now I'm curious...

Comment: Same name, different file triggers onchange. So now we know. Not very relevant, sorry, but at least now we know. (Even though the value is the exact same for JS.)

Comment: Could you please mark this as the accepted solution if this actually helped you. I have edited it to be more complete.

Comment: Talking to me? I'm not the OP.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I actually was trying with a different image and the problem persisted.

Answer (score 13):

Easiest way to fix this is to add an onclick and set the value to null every time.:

```
<input name="fileUpload" type="file" onclick="this.value = null"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

> **TL;DR:** Just reset the value attribute to empty("") right after using the file selector (using some event call backs or explicit
> function call)

**Synch** is partially right about onchange event that it will not fire for same file..More precisely onchange in case of input type file(scenario mentioned by **ether**) considers file location for event triggering.

> ##Try this out after selecting any file
> In jQuery
> `$("#image_message_upload [type='file']")[0].value`
>
> > You will get something like
> > "**C:\fakepath\country-and-mobile-redirect-for-wordpress-dwpsxm-clipar.jpg**" as output (that is the location of file selected)

That means either you change the file name or its location, which is not right. So, more logically what we can do while deleting the file is setting input value attribute to empty(**""**)

> `$("#image_message_upload [type='file']")[0].value=""`

So adding this line (inside clearPictureAttachment(), as per this question) will reset the file input type and you can select the same image file with no issues.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

In angular

HTML

```
<input #photoInput type="file" />
```

TS

```
export class SomeComponent {

 @ViewChild('photoInput') photoInput;

 clearPictureAttachment() {
  this.photoInput.nativeElement.value = '';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@Sync gave me the idea to solve this issue.

Here is the working code, what you need to do is to clone the file input.

```
var control = $('input[type=file]');
control.replaceWith( control = control.clone( true ) );
```

and the event will still be fired on second time.

Comment: Ah! That lead me on the right track. I just reenabled the onChange call and now it works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular, the following would be the easiest: 
`<input (change)="setImageValue($event)" (click)="inputImage.value = ''" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="file" #inputImage type="file">`

Comment: Please specify the version of angular you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Just because no changing accures.

you should reset it end of you codes:

```
$("#image-message").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have done what you want to do with the file, you can reset the FileList.

In my React app I have this:

```
const handleLoad = evt => {
  if (evt.target.files && evt.target.files[0]) {
    dispatch(loadFile(evt.target.files[0].path));
  }
  // Reset the FileList, as otherwise the second and subsequent times
  // we browse, nothing will happen, because nothing changed.
  evt.target.files = new FileList();
};
```

Comment: `new FileList()` does not seem to be supported in any browser (and the specification does not define a constructor). Are you sure it works for you?