# react cannot use fileinput twice without refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, file-upload

I'm using html fileinput to upload a file with reactjs, but once I uploaded a file, I cannot call the function to upload another file, unless I refresh the page of course.

A simplified version of my code would be:

```
class Matrice extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fileInput = null;
  }

  uploadQuestion = async e => {
    console.log("uploading question");
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      const form = new FormData();
      let type;
      if (e.target.files[0].type == "image/jpeg") type = ".jpg";
      if (e.target.files[0].type == "image/png") type = ".png";
      if (e.target.files[0].type == "image/gif") type = ".gif";
      // const fileName = this.props.current + type;
      form.append("files", e.target.files[0]); //filename
      form.append("ref", "exam"); // model
      form.append("refId", this.props.match.params.id); // id
      form.append("field", "media"); // name of field (image field)
      this.setState({ questionUploadLoading: true });
      const files = await strapi.upload(form);
      this.saveMontage(files, undefined, "question");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          ref={fileInput => (this.fileInput = fileInput)}
          onChange={this.uploadQuestion}
          className="file"
          type="file"
          id="imgAdd"
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => this.fileInput.click()}
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-secondary"
        >
          <i className="fas fa-image" />
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

But my function uploadQuestion cannot be called again once I finished uploading a file. Namely, the console.log('uploading question') doesn't show up (the second time).

I don't know what could be the reason, but I guess that something is preventing the onChange handler as if, uploading a file the second time doesn't "changes" the trigger.

Does anybody have an idea what could cause this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40429197/1398841

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reset the file `input` by setting its `value` to the empty string, and you will be able to use it again.

```
uploadQuestion = async (e) => {
    console.log('uploading question')
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
        // ...
        this.fileInput.value = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a heck of a time with this and no matter what I did from above nothing worked. Now, I've simply hardcoded the value to an empty string and I can upload over and over. I'm not even sure why this works, but I don't ever need the text value. The server cares about that. Here's a styled button using Material-UI where you never see the input, but you can upload over and over (in my case the server sends back some error and please fix your xlsx file message and I needed the user to be able to fix and try again):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import BackupIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Backup';

const UploadButton = ({ onChange, name, label, disabled }) => {
    return (
        <div className={'MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root'}>
            <input
                name={name}
                id='contained-button-file'
                type='file'
                accept='.csv, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
                style={{ display: 'none' }}
                onChange={onChange}
                disabled={disabled}
                value=''
            />
            <label htmlFor='contained-button-file'>
                <Button
                    color='primary'
                    aria-label='Upload scan file.'
                    variant='contained'
                    component='span'
                    startIcon={<BackupIcon />}
                    disabled={disabled}
                >
                    {label}
                    </Button>
            </label>
        </div>
    );
};

export default UploadButton;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the state for image that to be upload there is flow the step

1. Set a state for upload file in your Constructor (uploadFile:null)
2. Add a function for handle file Change
3. Use state upload(uploadFile) into uploadQuestion() instead of e.target.value[0]
4. After Upload setState back to uploadFile:null
5. set the file input onChange={this.fileHandle}

```
class Matrice extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state:{
            uploadFile:null
        }
        this.fileInput = null;
        this.fileHandle = this.fileHandle.bind(this)
    }

fileHandle (e, a) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ upload: e.target.files[0] })
  };

uploadQuestion = async (e) => {
    console.log('uploading question')
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
        const form = new FormData();
        let type;
        if (e.target.files[0].type == 'image/jpeg') type = '.jpg'
        if (e.target.files[0].type == 'image/png') type = '.png';
        if (e.target.files[0].type == 'image/gif') type = '.gif';
        // const fileName = this.props.current + type;
        //Use state upload(uploadFile) into uploadQuestion() instead of e.target.value[0]
        file.append('images', this.state.uploadFile, this.state.uploadFile.name) //filename
        form.append('ref', 'exam'); // model
        form.append('refId', this.props.match.params.id) // id
        form.append('field', 'media') // name of field (image field)
        this.setState({questionUploadLoading: true})
        const files = await strapi.upload(form);
        this.saveMontage(files, undefined, 'question')
        //After Upload setState back to uploadFile:null
        this.setState({uploadFile:null})
    }

}
```

if you like to valid in onChange you can modify function as Below

```
fileHandle (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (!e.target.files[0].name.match(/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)) {
      this.setState({ errorMsg: 'Please upload valid file. Allowed format jpg, jpeg, png, gif' })
      return false
    } else {
      this.setState({ upload: e.target.files[0], errorMsg: '' })
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Just handle it using click event**

```
const handleClick = event => {
    const { target = {} } = event || {};
    target.value = "";
  };

<input type="file" onChange={handleChange} onClick={handleClick} />
```