# Uploading File doesn't let me pick same file after i remove it from selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code that lets me select multiple files which i will then upload to server. I use input type='file' then im adding to list of files selected files( for example i can click button, select file 'A", then click same button again and select file "B" and my counter is 2). I also got a button to remove all files from selection(if you did mistake selecting files). Then when i try to re-select same files my counter is still set to 0. This problem doesn't occure if i select diffrent file, then remove it and select the file i wanted.
To make it more simple imagine you got files:

> FileA.jpg, FileB.jpg, FileC.png

When i select FileA counter goes to 1, then i click remove and counter goes back to 0.

Then i want to re-select same FileA but it doesnt count as selected, and counter is still set to 0 as long as i select the same file i did previously.

My state looks like this:

```
this.state={
          selectedFile:null,
          ile:0,
          lista:"",
       }
```

Here is my File handling:

```js
async handleRemove(){
    await this.setState({
      selectedFile:null,
      ile:0,
      lista:"",
      })
  data= new FormData();
  }

async handleSubmitFile(e) {
          await this.setState({selectedFile:e.target.files,})
          for(var x=0;x<this.state.selectedFile.length;x++){
                let rozszerzenie=this.state.selectedFile[x].name.split(".").pop();
                if(rozszerzenie.toUpperCase()==='PNG' || rozszerzenie.toUpperCase()==='JPEG' || rozszerzenie.toUpperCase()==='PDF' || rozszerzenie.toUpperCase()==='JPG')
                    {
                      data.append('images[]',this.state.selectedFile[x]);
                      if (this.state.lista.includes(this.state.selectedFile[x].name)){
                      }
                  else{await this.setState({
                      ile:this.state.ile+1,
                      lista:this.state.lista+this.state.selectedFile[x].name+"\n",
                  })
                  ;}
                }
                else{
                      alert("Błędny format pliku, proszę przesyłać tylko PNG, PDF oraz JPG/JPEG");
                      return;
                }  
              }
  }
```

And my Return just got simple

```js
<input type='file' onChange={this.handleSubmitFile} multiple name='file' id='image' accept='application/pdf, image/*'/>
{this.state.ile}- number of files selected
{this.state.lista}-list of all files
<button type="button" className="fileupdate" onClick={this.handleRemove}>Remove files</button>
```

I feel like it somehow remembers last selection and doesn't let re-select this. Any ideas how i can bypass that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='file' onChange={this.handleSubmitFile} multiple name='file' id='image' accept='application/pdf, image/*'/ value={this.state.selectedFile}>
```

You need to add value attribute to input, so when you clear the `selectedFile`, then your input should also be set as null, because onChange works with the change, so if the file is not changed it will not trigger.

Comment: Adding  `value={this.state.selectedFile}` just gives a wall of red errors in console, can't set the HTMLInputElement into value. Also using this.state.ile/lista doesnt work as well

Comment: you can change the value by using ref when you clear the selected file

Comment: Could you help me with that? haven't used references yet

Comment: Added `this.listRef=React.createRef();` before state,
changed handleRemove set State to `selectedFile:this.listRef.current.value`
and added to my input `ref={this.listRef} but that doesnt make this work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484895/how-to-allow-input-type-file-to-select-the-same-file-in-react-component/40429197

Answer (score 1):

After removing an element from the queue you need to clear the input value.

```
<input id="my-file" type="file" />

document.getElementById('my-file').value = "";
```