reactjs fileupload need to select twice to take effect
At first time, I click the button select a file then click upload, if the file is uploaded successfully then I re-select the file, I need to click choose a file  twice to select the file to take effect, otherwise it will display No file selected.. the following is the code.
const FactoryContactUpload = () => {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    // Handle the file change event
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);
  };
  const handleFileClick = (event) => {
    setShowAlert(false);
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    // Handle the upload event
    if (selectedFile) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", selectedFile);
      const token = await acquireTokenSilent(instance);
      apiClient
        .post("/factorycontact/upload", formData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          // Handle the API response
          setShowAlert(true);
          setAlertType("success");
          setAlertMessage(response.data.message || "");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Handle errors
          setShowAlert(true);
          setAlertType("error");
          setAlertMessage(error.response?.data?.message || "An error occurred");
        });
    } else {
      setShowAlert(true);
      setAlertType("info");
      setAlertMessage("No file selected.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <>
        <input
          type="file"
          onChange={handleFileChange}
          onClick={handleFileClick}
        />
        <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button>
        <br />
        <br />
      </>
      {showAlert && <Alert type={alertType} message={alertMessage} />}
    </div>
  );
};

Do any one know the problem?

Some code is missing. setAlertType, setAlertMessage and setAlertType are all undefined in the current snippet.

you can ignore that

Likely related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40429197/1086398. The onChange wont fire when selecting the same file. Try adding event.target.value = null inside handleFileClick.

in this case, it didn't work " onClick={(event)=> { setShowAlert(false); event.target.value = null }} " , setShowAlert(false); will block the  event.target.value = null
