# how to set a state for saving file data to null and upload the same?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a state with useState hook to hold the uploaded file's info. Initially the state is empty but whenever a file is selected by the user, it gets stored in the state. I have a X which on clicked, changes the state to null (like deleting). After deleting the current uploaded file, I am unable to upload the same file again but I am able to upload different file. Here is the code

App.js

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const fileInputRef = useRef();
  const [fileData, setFileData] = useState();
  const onSelectFile = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const file = fileInputRef.current.files[0];
      setFileData(file);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <section className="file-uplapd">
          <label
            htmlFor="file-upload"
            onClick={() => fileInputRef.current.click()}
          >
            Click or Drag to Upload
          </label>
          <input
            id="file-upload"
            type="file"
            hidden
            ref={fileInputRef}
            onChange={(e) => onSelectFile(e)}
          />
          {!!fileData && (
            <div className="file-data-container">
              <h3> {fileData.name} </h3>
              <h1
                style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}
                onClick={() => setFileData(null)}
              >
                {" "}
                X{" "}
              </h1>
            </div>
          )}
        </section>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

How may I fix this?

Code Sandbox Link for Preview : https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-mayer-6w2wz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as in the other answer by click2install, You don't need a ref; you can use the label as intended and take the file value from the event.target.files[0]. (Use a div or section instead of label to avoid triggering file picker twice)

But in this approach, because you are just clearing the fileData state, not the value in fileInputRef, it still holds the same name of the file that the user previously uploaded. So, you need to set it also to null.

```
<h1 style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}
    onClick={() => {
       fileInputRef.current.value = null;
       setFileData(null);
     }}>
 X
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `ref`, you can just use the `label` as intended and take the file value from the `event` data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `event.target`'s value to be able to upload the same file.

The reasoning for this is that the value hasn't changed from the HTML file picker point of view when you select the same file. And this doesn't trigger the onChange handler. By resetting the value to an empty string (or null), the onChange handler is triggered properly.

```
  const onSelectFile = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const file = fileInputRef.current.files[0];
      setFileData(() => {
        e.target.value = "";
        return file;
      });
    }
  };
```

In the above code, I've used the callback mode of `setState` to reset the `event.target.value` to empty string, This guarantees the file object is captured by the state and the reset happens as expected.
Using `setFileData(file); e.target.value = "";` can have an unintended consequence of resetting the value *before* the state is set.

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56258902/1782471

Comment: Thanks I wanted to know more about the useRef so i created this question